# Can't map windows 7 to Ubuntu 16.04 samba share

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, samba, file-sharing, sharing

When I do Windows 7 > file explorer > map network drive to my share:
\10.0.0.24\home\Ubuntu
I get this error:

```
Windows cannot access..
```

Windows 7 can ping Ubuntu.

Here is what I did to setup samba at Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
appended:
[Nitro6_file_system]
  comment = Nitro6 Ubuntu File Server Share
  path = /home/ubuntu
  browsable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  read only = no
  create mask = 0755
..to the end of /etc/samba/smb.conf
Restarted samba:
sudo systemctl restart smbd.service nmbd.service
```

I've tried restarting Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows will not be able to access `\\10.0.0.24\home\Ubuntu` as that is the target of the actual share.  You access your share by putting in the name within the `[ ]` from your `smb.conf` file.  Your share name is `Nitro6_file_system`.

To access your share you should be accessing it at:

```
\\10.0.0.24\Nitro6_file_system
```

Hope this helps!